# Enabling minimum apiVersion to 2021-08-01 in Azure API Management causing saving issues or deployment errors for existing logic apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-resource-manager, azure-api-management, apim

After having saved or enabled rather the minimum apiVersion for API Management to 2021-08-01, I cannot save or deploy (via ARM templates) my logic apps that have API management connectors within the logic app, which are making API calls to the APIM. The error given when deploying the ARM template is:

```
"message":"{\"Message\":\"The service is configured to allow management requests only with the following api-version values: 2021-08-01, 2021-12-01-preview, 2022-04-01-preview, 2022-08-01, 2022-09-01-preview, 2023-03-01-preview, 2023-05-01-preview, 2023-09-01-preview\"}
```

The ARM template for the logic looks something like this:

```
 "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {}
"resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
        "apiVersion": "2017-07-01",
        "name": "[parameters('logicAppName')]",
        "location": "eastus",
        "tags": "[parameters('resourceTags')]",
        "properties": {
            "state": "Enabled",
            "definition": {
                "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
                "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                ....
                ....
             }
```

I tried changing the dates for the schema or apiVersion in the ARM template, but that is not working since it looks like 2019-04-01 is the latest one can use. I also experimented by creating a new logic in the Azure portal and adding a new API management connector but I get the following error shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

This issue came about because Microsoft announced the [retirement of API versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/breaking-changes/api-version-retirement-sep-2023#required-action). Is there a way to fix this error within the logic app's ARM template or the logic app itself from the Azure portal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, I've just checked it, and enforcing the minimum API version in the API Management service does break the `Azure API Management` connector both in Consumption Logic Apps and in Standard Logic Apps.

I don't see what else can be done apart from replacing the `Azure API Management` actions in your workflows with [`HTTP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http?tabs=consumption) actions.